# How to extract numbers in a text row and seperate by a delimiter

Tags: r, gsub

I am currently extracting all numbers appearing in a string like below:

```
    library(data.table)
    library(stringr)

    Data<-data.table(
    X=sample(1:10),
    Y=c("before 10 pm","1-3 am","at 3pm","after 4pm","on 12:00am","at 16:00","between 12-12:30","at 1PM","1.30-2pm","11.00AM - 1.00PM")
    )
    fun1<-function(x){
    ge<-gregexpr("(^-?|(?<=\\D)-)?(\\d\\.?\\d*?)+",x,perl=T)
    return(as.numeric(sapply(regmatches(x,ge),paste0,collapse="")))
    }

    Data[,parsed:=lapply(Y,fun1)]
```

But this extracts the numbers and I need to seperate them by a delimiter .For example 1.30-2pm should be parsed into 1_30_2 .Eventually i need to get the time window from these reviews. Is this approach good ?

Comment: @Anony-MousseI I am just a beginner and could you guide me to what is the best approach ?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to handle such data at all. These values have very different semantics. Why can't you just leave them as they are? What do you intend to do anyway?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse well I need to extract the time window depending on the time they specify.Like before 2pm= 08:00-14:00 1.30-2pm =13:30-14:00.so then it will be in structured format and easy to do further analysis

Comment: But for that you likely won't want to lose the difference between "before 2pm" and "after 2pm"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_extract_all to extract all numbers in each string, then if you want them together in a single string separated by _, you can use paste with _ as the collapse argument. I don't think this will help you get the time periods though, you would need some assumptions about the patterns possibly taken by the entries.

```
Data[, parsed := sapply(str_extract_all(Y, '\\d+'), paste, collapse = '_')]

Data    
#      X                Y     parsed
#  1:  1     before 10 pm         10
#  2:  4           1-3 am        1_3
#  3:  3           at 3pm          3
#  4:  7        after 4pm          4
#  5:  2       on 12:00am      12_00
#  6:  8         at 16:00      16_00
#  7:  5 between 12-12:30   12_12_30
#  8:  6           at 1PM          1
#  9:  9         1.30-2pm     1_30_2
# 10: 10 11.00AM - 1.00PM 11_00_1_00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using chained `gsub`.

```
gsub("_$", "", gsub("\\D*(\\d+)\\D*", "\\1_", Data$Y))
# [1] "10"         "1_3"        "3"          "4"          "12_00"      "16_00"     
# [7] "12_12_30"   "1"          "1_30_2"     "11_00_1_00"
```